# Parsing HTML to get script variable value

Tags: c#, javascript, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to find a method of accessing data between  tags returned by a server I am making HTTP requests to. The document has multiple  tags, but only one of the tags has JavaScript code between it, the rest are included from files. I want to accesses the code between the script tag.

An example of the code is:

```
<html>
    // Some HTML

    <script>
        var spect = [['temper', 'init', []],
                    ['fw\/lib', 'init', [{staticRoot: '//site.com/js/'}]],
                    ["cap","dm",[{"tackmod":"profile","xMod":"timed"}]]];

    </script>

    // More HTML
</html>
```

I'm looking for an ideal way to grab the data between 'spect' and parse it. Sometimes there is a space between 'spect' and the '=' and sometimes there isn't. No idea why, but I have no control over the server.

I know this question may have been asked, but the responses suggest using something like HTMLAgilityPack, and I'd rather avoid using a library for this task as I only need to get the JavaScript from the DOM once.

Comment: that's exactly why you use it,with 2 or 3 lines of code you can extract that script content with HTMLAgilityPack and then just parse it with a regex or even a JavaScript evaluator to get the value of spect which would simplify the entire work of parsing it with a regex.

Comment: Sorry, but if you can't write code yourself in 5 minutes it may be indication of problem being more complex than you initially thought - that is why existing solutions exist :). It is somewhat hard to see what your goal actually is - do you want to learn something new, do you have any explicit restrictions not to use external libraries, do you want to practice writing particular kind of code?

Comment: I solved it by writing a regular expression, will answer own question in a moment. The reason I wanted to avoid using a library because this is the only point in the application I will need to parse this bit of JavaScript. I thought of it as bad practice to use a library for this one task when theoretically it's possible without one. The reason why I asked is to learn what other options may be available for solving this problem. I face this problem numerous times in other projects and usually end up using CsQuery or HTMLAgilityPack, but for this one call I wanted to avoid them libraries.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Very simple example of how this could be easy using a **[HTMLAgilityPack](http://html-agility-pack.net/)** and [**Jurassic library**](https://github.com/paulbartrum/jurassic) to evaluate the result:

```
var html = @"<html>
             // Some HTML
             <script>
               var spect = [['temper', 'init', []],
               ['fw\/lib', 'init', [{staticRoot: '//site.com/js/'}]],
               [""cap"",""dm"",[{""tackmod"":""profile"",""xMod"":""timed""}]]];
             </script>
             // More HTML
             </html>";

// Grab the content of the first script element
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
var script = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants()
                             .Where(n => n.Name == "script")
                             .First().InnerText;

// Return the data of spect and stringify it into a proper JSON object
var engine = new Jurassic.ScriptEngine();
var result = engine.Evaluate("(function() { " + script + " return spect; })()");
var json = JSONObject.Stringify(engine, result);

Console.WriteLine(json);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Output:

> [["temper","init",[]],["fw/lib","init",[{"staticRoot":"//site.com/js/"}]],["cap","dm",[{"tackmod":"profile","xMod":"timed"}]]]

**Note:** I am not accounting for errors or anything else, this merely serves as an example of how to grab the script and evaluate for the value of spect.

There are a few other libraries for executing/evaluating JavaScript as well.

Comment: Although I opted to use a regular expression, I actually like this answers as I've never used Jurassic and it'll defiantly come in handy in future projects.

Comment: @buffer_overflow make a new question with your problem and I am sure some one will help you out with it.

Comment: I have put a question here but seems like no response.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23636885/html-agility-pack-missing-a-script-in-html-parsing

Comment: @buffer_overflow its been barely a day since you posted it, just wait and some one will help you out with it! Remember this is not a paid service website, where you would post and get an instant answer that solves every and all of your issues.

Comment: What if the script needs to read DOM? Can we pass HTML into Jurassic?