# C# HTMLAgilityPack get content <script>

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I want to get the contents of this script

```
<script language="javascript">
    //some content
</script>
```

How to do it using HTMLAgilityPack?

Comment: Did you try anything, or are you simply specifying a job for strangers to do for you?

Comment: [How to use HTML Agility pack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/how-to-use-html-agility-pack?rq=1) or [Parsing HTML to get script variable value](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18157325/342740)

Answer (score 5):

Did you try?

doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("script")