# Crawl a webpage and grab all dynamic Javascript links

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I am using C# to crawl a website. All works fine except it can't detect dynamic JS links. As an example, a page with over 100 products may have few pages and the "Next Page"m "Prev Page" link may JS dynamic urls which is generated on click. Typical JS code is below:

```
<a href="javascript:PageURL('
        cf-233--televisions.aspx','?',2);">&gt;</a>
```

Is there anyway of getting the actual link of the above href while collecting urls on the page ?

I am using Html Agility Pack but open to any other technology. I tried google this many times but seems no solution yet.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to evaluate javascript to get actual hrefs? It might be helpful [Parsing HTML to get script variable value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18156795/parsing-html-to-get-script-variable-value)

Or maybe you should check what PageURL function does (Just open the website with a browser and write at it's console PageURL without parentheses. It will show you code of the function) and rewrite it with C#

Comment: Thanks.. but this is a crawler so need to automate for all the cases. As an example, web browser can simply identify all the urls including href HTML tags as well as JS urls. Similar to the browser, my crawler need to identify all urls. There could be many other ways to generate dynamic url's on a page.

Comment: Yeah. In general case there may be any javascript code, not necessarily referencing some recourse. So it probably best to just skip those hrefs. If it is not acceptable, then you should manually handle each particular case.

Answer (score 0):

[AbotX](https://abotx.org/) allows you to render the javascript on the page. Its a powerful web crawler with advanced features.