# How to extract attribute value that is within script tags?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, xpath, html-agility-pack

**General**

I am currently playing around with HTML and Javascript in order to use the changing value of a website (temperature, stock value, currency exchange rate, ...) for a C# application.

(I am intentionally ignoring the [unclear legal situation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping).)

**Specifics**

I have a website and its source code. My desired value is within script tags.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="TmplLiveEventDetails">
    <div class="lii-progress">
        <span ng-bind="liveEvent.eventStateText"></span> <strong class="m-liveGameTime{{::liveEvent.id}}"></strong><br/>
<!--code goes on here...-->
```

I want to use the value of the class

```
m-liveGameTime
```

in my C# application.

**What I have tried so far**

I started with the HtmlAgilityPack and XPath, but it took me some time to figure out that it does not work with JavaScript. 
Then I followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18156795/parsing-html-to-get-script-variable-value), where HtmlAgilityPack and Jurassic are used. But again, not working as I hoped.

I am able to plain-text extract what´s within the script tag, but I obviously need to get the HTML not via HtmlAgilityPack but rather something that is evaluating the Javascript expressions first.

A snippet of my code, just for clarity:

```
    string url = "http://www.somewebsite.com";

    HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
    HtmlDocument document = web.Load(url);

    string scriptContent = document.DocumentNode.Descendants()
                          .Where(n => n.Id == "TmplLiveEventDetails")
                          .First().InnerHtml;


    var engine = new Jurassic.ScriptEngine();
    var result = engine.Evaluate("function() {" + scriptContent + " return m-liveGameTime4902493; })()");
```

**Considerations**

I am a total beginner with HTML and Javascript, and this really is a short side project to try something. If the answer is that I need to comprehensively look at HTML and Javascript first in order to do what I want, I gladly take that advice.

But I would prefer an answer that I can use immediately.

Answer (score 0):

What if you try to parse the page source (you can get that easily with Selenium webdriver and then apply some regex on it to extract the value that you need)?

Comment: I'll give it a look!